# converting my time to DateTime

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have a datetime as a string where I'm trying to put it into a DateTime object. I have used `Get-Culture` and I am en-nz which is what I want.

The string is:
`13/10/2014 02:13:02 p.m.`

I've tried some methods such as casting it to a dateTime object with `[datetime]` but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I do this in powershell?

Edit: I'm using powershell, so .NET functions might work as well.

Thanks.

Comment: In which language? C# or Powershell?

Comment: I am using powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting will only work for US format or ISO-8601 in PowerShell. Think of casting a string to `DateTime` as sort of a `DateTime` literal. That way there can be no locale dependencies in scripts that might break (which is a common occurrence with batch files, for example).

Generally, if you're working with strings in a specific culture, you need to use `[DateTime]::Parse` and its ilk (likewise with other data types like numbers).

In this case, though, it seems like `en-nz` is the wrong culture to parse this with anyway:

```
PS Home:\> [DateTime]::Parse('13/10/2014 02:13:02 p.m.', [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-nz'))
Exception calling "Parse" with "2" argument(s): "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an
unknown word starting at index 20."
At line:1 char:1
+ [DateTime]::Parse('13/10/2014 02:13:02 p.m.', [cultureinfo]::GetCultu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

The problem is the `p.m.` which only very few cultures have:

```
PS Home:\> [cultureinfo]::GetCultures('AllCultures')|?{[DateTime]::Now.ToString($_) -match 'p\.m\.'}

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
112              ig               Igbo
1136             ig-NG            Igbo (Nigeria)
4096             luy              Luluhia
4096             luy-KE           Luluhia (Kenya)
129              mi               Maori
1153             mi-NZ            Maori (New Zealand)
134              quc              K'iche'
31878            quc-Latn         K'iche'
1158             quc-Latn-GT      K'iche' (Guatemala)
107              quz              Quechua
1131             quz-BO           Quechua (Bolivia)
3179             quz-PE           Quechua (Peru)
```

`mi-NZ` looks good, though:

```
PS Home:\> [DateTime]::Parse('13/10/2014 02:13:02 p.m.', [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('mi-nz'))

Montag, 13. Oktober 2014 14:13:02
```

Comment: That's good, but it's still coming out as `Monday, 13 October 2014 2:13:02 p.m.` instead of `13/10/2014` format. Is there a way to do it to retain this format?

Comment: What's printed is just the long form of the `DateTime` object. The result *is* actually a `DateTime`. This format is for your convenience that you don't see `[System.DateTime]` or something similar. If you want a specific format you can use `ToString` with a format string (and a culture, if needed): `$d = [datetime]::Parse('13/10/2014 02:13:02 p.m.', [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('mi-nz')); $d.ToString([cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('mi-nz'))`.

Comment: Keep in mind, PowerShell works with objects usually. Just because you see a particular text doesn't mean that this is actually a string. If you want a string, you usually have to make one yourself.

Comment: Yes. By using the [`ToString` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with an appropriate [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As noted above, by the way. As also noted above, you may want/need to supply the correct culture as well.